# Setting hibernate fetch size in Spring boot

Tags: java, hibernate

How to set the hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size property in Spring boot Application?

Can this be set into application.properties?

Comment: Try to use `spring.jpa.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size` in the `application.properties`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the prefix `spring.jpa.properties.`

Check the official docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-jpa-properties)

So, in the end, your properties should look like this: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size`