# Spring Data repository: set fetch size as a parameter

Tags: spring, hibernate, dependency-injection, spring-data

I have a Spring Data repository like this:

```
public interface MyRepo extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

    @QueryHints(@javax.persistence.QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.fetchSize", value="${fetch.size}"))
    List<MyEntity> findAll();

}
```

I added fetch.size=100 into application.properties but get this error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${fetch.size}"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.ConfigurationHelper.getInteger(ConfigurationHelper.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setHint(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1035)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setHint(AbstractProducedQuery.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.setHint(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.setHint(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.applyQueryHints(SimpleJpaRepository.java:766)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.applyRepositoryMethodMetadata(SimpleJpaRepository.java:758)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:678)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:655)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:346)
```

Does Spring support this type of property injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: **you cannot include a dynamic value in `QueryHints` annotation**. It is possible to do something like:

```
@QueryHints(@javax.persistence.QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.fetchSize", value="" + Integer.MAX_VALUE))
```

but, as `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, only constants are allowed.

So basically you have the following options:

---

### Include it in a property file

Add the required value in your property file, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60372230/setting-hibernate-fetch-size-in-spring-boot)

---

### Get internal Entity Manager

Here you have to face up two main problems:

1. Include desired `fetchSize` value into your query.
2. Get `fetchSize` value from a property file and use it in an interface.

For the **second one**, you can take a look a workaround [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-static-field). An easier example:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Constant {

  public static int FETCH_SIZE;

  @Value("${fetch.size}")
  public void setFetchSizeStatic(int fetchSize){
    Constant.FETCH_SIZE = fetchSize;
  }
}
```

For the **first point**, more changes are required:

**1.1** Create a custom `Repository` to have access to `EntityManager`:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.io.Serializable;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ExtendedJpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

  /**
   * Return the internal {@link EntityManager} to provide more functionality to the repositories
   *
   * @return {@link EntityManager}
   */
  EntityManager getEntityManager();
}



import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ExtendedJpaRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements ExtendedJpaRepository<T, ID> {

  private EntityManager entityManager;

  public ExtendedJpaRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
  }


  @Override
  public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
  }
}
```

**1.2** Configure the new Repositories:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "PATH_TO_YOUR_REPOSITORIES", repositoryBaseClass = ExtendedJpaRepositoryImpl.class)
public class PersistenceConfiguration { }
```

Now it will be possible to create a custom `Repository`, configuring a dynamic value for a hint:

```
import org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints;

@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends ExtendedJpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

  default List<MyEntity> findAll() {
    return getEntityManager().createQuery("select e "
                                        + "from MyEntity e ", MyEntity.class)
            .setHint( QueryHints.HINT_FETCH_SIZE, Constant.FETCH_SIZE )
            .getResultList();
  }
}
```

---

Comment: I'd rather prefer jdbcTemplate in that case :)

Comment: Yes, it has a method to include the desired value: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#setFetchSize-int- you can set in your custom `JdbcTemplate` bean creation method